# PIL fromstring error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a png picture, and i need to save it as string, and then open it again with PIL. I'm trying to do it like that:

```
output = StringIO.StringIO()
old_image.save(output, format="PNG")
contents = output.getvalue()
output.close()

new_image = Image.fromstring(contents, "RGBA", old_image.size)
```

but it gives me an error: `TypeError: 'argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str'`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the arguments reversed:

```
Image.fromstring(mode, size, data, decoder_name='raw', *args)
```

so

```
Image.fromstring("RGBA", old_image.size, contents)
```

But note that it's much easier to read from the `StringIO` object directly:

```
output = StringIO.StringIO()
old_image.save(output, format="PNG")

output.seek(0)
new_image = Image.open(output)
```